# Print to file without interaction similar to word macro. .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, powershell, automation

I'm attempting to automate printing images with Microsoft Office Document Image Writer to pre-determined file-names and locations without user interaction.

I have achieved this with word documents using
    objWdDoc.PrintOut(PrintToFile:=True, OutputFileName:=sDestination & sFileName & ".tif")

I have yet to find a solution, without 3rd party software, to "print to file" without the dialog popping up. Any suggestions with .Net?
I can load the image into a form object if that will make it possible, or just pass the file location.

I also tried the shell command where you send the print verb but that requires manually entering the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = True
PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = outTiff
PrintDocument1.Print()
```

Then with the PrintDocument1 PrintFile event, the image is loaded.

```
Dim newImage As Image = CType(mBitmap, Image)
e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, 5, 5)
```